# Http Status Code 404: This is being deprecated and will be not be available in future releases of Analytics JS

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

I am using Google analytics in one of our website for measuring how users interact with the website. I see there is a warning message in the console that something related to Analytics JS is been deprecated but not sure what exactly is been deprecated. Has anyone encountered the same issue and how much of an impact this will have on the tracking? attaching the screenshot below for reference.

**Update:**
I just found out that this is happening when any of the service call returns a 404 response across the application.

```
a[f] = function() {
  try {
      var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      d.log.add("c", {
          timestamp: d.util.isoNow(),
          severity: f,
          message: d.serialize(1 === a.length ? a[0] : a)
      });
      if (b[f])
          if (e.isError(a[0]) && 1 === a.length)
              d.onError("console", a[0]);
          else
              try {
                  throw Error(d.serialize(1 === a.length ? a[0] : a));
              } catch (c) {
                  d.onError("console", c)
              }


      b.display && (d.util.hasFunction(l, "apply") ? 
l.apply(this, a) : l(a[0])) // **THIS LINE IS HAVING THE ISSUE**


  } catch (c) {
      d.onFault(c)
  }
}
```

[image]

Any inputs will be appreciated

Comment: On your screenshot (in the console), on the very right, see tracker.js:13 ? click on it. It will show you code. Something that is being called on the 13th line is being deprecated.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the contents of tracker.js at line 13?   We can't answer this question without this information.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i have added the code

Comment: Probably `d.serialize` that is deprecated then.